# Adding paths to file names that scanned with nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have this route in my app. Its scanning file names in some directories according to url parameter. Currently my JSON looks like;

```
[{"chapter":"642","paths":["00.png","01.png","02.png","03.png","04.png","05.png".....
```

Route:

```
app.get('/api/oku/:name', function (req, res) {
    var files = fs.readdirSync('./public/manga/' + req.params.name);
    var files = files.map(function(item){
        var subfolders = fs.readdirSync('./public/manga/' + req.params.name + '/' + item);
        return {
            chapter: item,
            paths: subfolders
        }
    })
    res.json(files);
})
```

Simply I want to add paths to every image. Path that I want to add is;

```
"manga/" + req.params.name + "/" + item + "/"
```

So simply it will be looks like `manga/Naruto/542/00.png`

Comment: What did you tried? Why did it fail?

Comment: @DrakaSAN I try `for each` but that doesnt supported by nodejs.

Comment: Couldn't you just map through the subfolders variable?

Comment: Map is fine for that job, what I meant is, you stated you want your list to look like X, but if I execute your code right now, what is the output, and why is it wrong?

Comment: @DrakaSAN I am displaying these images on the frontend and its require paths. I dont how to edit that code its written with Angular. When I try to add path to `ng-src` at frontend everything is messes up and I dont know how to fix it. So simply changing this is easier to other way.

Comment: When you execute the code you posted, what is the resulting JSON?

Comment: @DrakaSAN Its in my post. `[{"chapter":"642","paths":["00.png","01.png","02.png","03.png","04.png","05.png".....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    app.get('/api/oku/:name', function (req, res) {
    var files = fs.readdirSync('./public/manga/' + req.params.name).map(function(item){
        var subfolders = fs.readdirSync('./public/manga/' + req.params.name + '/' + item);
        return {
            chapter: item,
            paths: subfolders.map(function (i) {
                return "manga/" + req.params.name + "/" + i + "/";
            }
        }
    })
    res.json(files);
})
```

Also, don't declare the files variable twice.

Comment: Ok thanks. Its works. `return "manga/" + req.params.name + "/" + item+ "/" +i;`